# Embedding Python app in c app

Tags: c, python-2.7, shared-libraries, embed

I am on integration of a c library to python application.
and i need to pass a list of variables from python size to a wrapper of C lib(which i am calling) just for understanding, i have written a small program:
After loading shared lib in python app.
In Python side:

```
 c_args = [5,6]
 PyPrintVal(c_args)
```

In C side:

```
PyPrintVal(PyObject *c_args)
{
       int i=0;
       int j=0;
       printf("In eINoiseRemoval\n");
       if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(c_args, "ii", &i,&j))
       {      fprintf(stderr, "error in parsing\n");
              return -1;
       }
       printf(i1=%d   j=%d\n, i,j)
}
```

then I am getting segmentation fault ? Is there anything left?
for that i am looking http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example

but not getting any answer.
Thanks

Comment: Call `PyPrintVal(*c_args)`.

Comment: I mean: call `PyPrintVal(*c_args)` in python side.

Comment: right ctypes. from ctypes import * ; handle=CDLL( "example.so" ); PyPrintVal=handle.PyPrintVal; PyPrintVal.argtypes = [py_object]

Comment: thanks falsetru,  done !! by PyList_GetItem(,) call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gdb` to find out exactly where this segfault is:

```
$ gdb python
......
> set args my_python_script.py
> run
.......
Segmentation Fault
> where
```

This will give you a stack trace and point you to the exact location of the segfault.

Comment: and now it looks like this  i = PyInt_AsLong(PyList_GetItem(c_Arg, 0));  i = PyInt_AsLong(PyList_GetItem(c_Arg, 0));  printf(i=%d   j=%d\n, i,j);    output i=5  j=6